# Eclim for jsp files

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclim

Is it possible to use eclim plugin on `.jsp` files (vim inside of eclipse)?

I have tried auto-completion with eclim on a jsp file, but it shows me an exception `IllegalArgumentException`: Compilation unit name must end with .java, or one of the registered Java-like extensions...

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by breakpoints. Try to remove them and save the files.